# Add relative line numbers in neo-tree using Lazy in Neovim

Tags: lua, neovim

Just starting to learn Neovim and I m struggling with something that might be a simple to fix for someone experienced.

Using LazyVim distribution for Neovim which internally use `Lazy.nvim` as plugin manager and uses [neo-tree](https://github.com/nvim-neo-tree/neo-tree.nvim) as one of the plugins.

I want to configure neo-tree plugin to show relative line numbers in its file explorer.

Using [this](https://github.com/nvim-tree/nvim-tree.lua/issues/422#issuecomment-1010372867) and [this](https://github.com/LazyVim/starter/blob/741ff3aa70336abb6c76ee4c49815ae589a1b852/lua/plugins/example.lua#L63) as referance, I made a new file in `plugins/neo-tree.lua` with this as contents:

```lua
return {
  {
    "nvim-neo-tree/neo-tree.nvim",
      opts = {
        view = {
           relativenumber = true,
        },
    },
  },
}
```

Now after this, when I restart, I should see line number but I don't. What could go wrong here?

Note: When I m in the neo-tree buffer and i `set number`, I see line numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `relativenumber` option for the `nvim-neo-tree/neo-tree.nvim` plugin. You are confusing with the `nvim-tree/nvim-tree.lua` plugin ([discussion about this option](https://github.com/nvim-tree/nvim-tree.lua/discussions/1578)).

For the `neo-tree.nvim` plugin, you could enable relativenumber with Lazy via `event_handlers`:

```lua
return {
  "nvim-neo-tree/neo-tree.nvim",
  opts = {
    event_handlers = {
      event = "neo_tree_buffer_enter",
      handler = function()
        vim.opt_local.relativenumber = true
      end,
    },
  },
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```lua
return {
  "nvim-neo-tree/neo-tree.nvim",
  opts = {
    event_handlers = {
      {
        event = "neo_tree_buffer_enter",
        handler = function(arg)
          vim.cmd([[
              setlocal relativenumber
            ]])
        end,
      },
    },
  }
}
```

You can refer to https://www.reddit.com/r/neovim/comments/16siats/show_my_neotree_config_allow_you_to_telescope/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).